# How can I define a map whose values contain a fixed length array of type String?

Tags: arrays, scala, dictionary

I'm attempting to represent the basic strategy of a blackjack game as a map with integer keys whose values are a fixed length array of strings.
The keys represent the value of the player's hand, the array index represents the value of the dealers up card (hence the fixed length array of size 10 corresponding to card values 2-11).  The string value in the array at the position corresponding to the dealer's up card contains the ideal play (stay, hit, split, double).

IE) player hand value is a hard 8, dealer up card is a 2.  Basic strategy says the player should hit.  To determine this using my map, I would get the array whose key is 8(player hand value = 8) and then looking at the string in array index 0 (Dealer up card = 2).

I've attempted to define it this way:

```
val hardHandBasicStrategy = collection.mutable.Map[Int,Array[String](10)]
```

but Scala doesn't seem to like this...

Please help me understand what I've done wrong, and/or suggest a way to make it work.

Comment: You cannot represent the length of the array as a type. Simple put arrays of length ten there and remove the number (and the parens).

Comment: Ahh, so the problem is that the map definition needs a type, and not an array of a specific length?  is the suggestion that I should use `val hardHandBS = collection.mutable.Map[Int,Array[String]]`

Comment: Eclipse doesn't like that...  it highlights the first bracket, the one before "Int" in `[Int,Array[String]]` and the IDE suggestion says "missing arguments for method apply in class GenMapFactory; follow this method with `_' if you want to treat 
 it as a partially applied function"

Comment: This is what ended up working: `val hardHandBS = collection.mutable.Map[Int,Array[String]](10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala doesn't have a type that represents arrays of a fixed size.  You can either simply use arrays of size ten--this is what is normally done--or, if you want stronger guarantees that it really is size ten, you can construct a ten-long-array-class yourself:

```
class ArrayTen[T: ClassManifest](zero: T) {
  protected val data = Array.fill(10)(zero)
  def apply(i: Int) = data(i)
  def update(i: Int, t: T) { data(i) = t }
  protected def set(ts: Array[T]) { for (i <- data.indices) data(i) = ts(i) }
  def map[U: ClassManifest](f: T => U) = { 
    val at = new ArrayTen(null.asInstanceOf[U])
    at.set(data.map(f))
    at
  }
  def foreach(f: T => Unit) { data.map(f) }
  override def toString = data.mkString("#10[",",","]")
  override def hashCode = scala.util.MurmurHash.arrayHash(data)
  override def equals(a: Any) = a match {
    case a: ArrayTen[_] => (data,a.data).zipped.forall(_ == _)
    case _ => false
  }
  // Add other methods here if you really need them
}
```

Example:

```
scala> new ArrayTen("(nothing)")
res1: ArrayTen[java.lang.String] = 
  #10[(nothing),(nothing),(nothing),(nothing),(nothing),
  (nothing),(nothing),(nothing),(nothing),(nothing)]

scala> res1(3) = "something!!!"

scala> res1
res3: ArrayTen[java.lang.String] = 
  #10[(nothing),(nothing),(nothing),something!!!,(nothing),
  (nothing),(nothing),(nothing),(nothing),(nothing)]
```

If you need the the fixed-length array to take a parameter that determines the length, then you should

```
trait Size { size: Int }
class ArraySize[S <: Size, T: ClassManifest](zero: T, s: Size) {
  protected val data = Array.fill(s.size)(zero)
  ...
}
```

You won't have all the collections goodies unless you reimplement them, but then again you don't *want* most of the goodies, since most of them can change the length of the array.

Comment: Could I forego the creation of a new class by relaxing the requirement that the array be fixed at size 10, and simply filling the arrays with 10 values after the map is created?

Comment: @NickAbbey - Yes, you can.  I thought you wanted a type-safe length for your array, so I answered accordingly.

Comment: I thought I did, but your suggestion lead me to realize that my requirements were making it harder than it needed to be :)